# How to avoid undesirable dependencies in rpm package?

Tags: perl, dependencies, rpmbuild

I am making a package for RHEL7.  When I try to install the package, I get

```
# yum localinstall mypackage-0.0-1.el7.rpm 
(...)
--> Running transaction check
---> Package webmin-GPI-init.noarch 0:0.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(.::guardian-lib.pl) for package: webmin-GPI-init-0.0-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(.::hostconfig-lib.pl) for package: webmin-GPI-init-0.0-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(.::init-lib.pl) for package: webmin-GPI-init-0.0-1.el7.noarch
```

I have in mind that willing to get a perl module named `.::init-lib.pl` is not desirable.  In the code, we can find something like

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
require './init-lib.pl';
require './guardian-lib.pl'; 
require './hostconfig-lib.pl';
```

I have managed to remove the `win32` with the following option in my `.spec` file :

```
%{?perl_default_filter}
%global __requires_exclude perl\\(VMS|perl\\(Win32|perl\\(\\.
```

How can I get rid of the dependencies regarding the perl packages that start by a dot?

I have browsed the Internet and found https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:AutoProvidesAndRequiresFiltering and other mailing lists I have not understood.

Comment: Also, I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715955/how-can-i-rebuild-rpm-package-exclude-some-dependencies which enables to disable totally this functionality.  This is a bit overkill, but enables the package to be installed.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source RPM? In some fooling around I cannot get a test RPM to generate `./foo.pl` provides or requires as yours is.

Comment: I do not think that generating pseudo/void dependencies is the answer, it is a programming trick.  I do think that not to generate stupid dependencies is a good answer.

Comment: coded, not checked, but I think `%global __requires_exclude perl\\((VMS|Win32|\\..*)\\)` might be very close to what you want [though not sure from your question why VMS or Win32 are in your proposed regex at all]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rpmbuild analyses the content of your rpm package to automatically determine what is required for your program to work. If you use certain perl modules; those need to be installed for your program to work.

However, if you don't want rpm to do all that work for you; you can add

```
AutoReqProv : no
```

to your spec file. For more information; [read this](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use:

```
%define __requires_exclude ^perl(\s|)\(.*\)$
```